# How to see the source of a popup that a browser opens (from FireFox or Chrome)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, selenium, firefox

**The question**: I need to see the html source of a *popup* that a browser opens: how do I see that source from `FireFox` or `Chrome`?

I'm using `Selenium IDE` to record a conversion of a *mobi* file to *epub* file.
 The last part of the procedure is to choose the `save as` and press the <kbd>OK</kbd> button.
The issue is that <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> in the popup window doesn't open a drop-down menu to view the source.

**So, how can I see the source code of the popup?**

---

### **`Background`**

**`The Selenium IDE commands:`**

[image: Selenium IDE]

**`The HTML source code:`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://ebook.online-convert.com/convert-to-epub" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/convert-to-epub</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>css=h1</td>
    <td>Convert text to the ePub ebook format</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>css=li &gt; label</td>
    <td>Upload your document you want to convert to EPUB :</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=file</td>
    <td>C:\tmp\incoming\Top 100 Science Fiction and Fantasy Books as Voted by NPR-P2P(Epub, Mobi)\11. The Princess Bride by William Goldman\William Goldman - Princess Bride_ S. Morgenstern_The (v4.0).mobi</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=submit_button</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPopUp</td>
    <td>timeout</td>
    <td>60000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>&quot;OK&quot;</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dialog boxes are not pages.

Comment: Regardless of how they are defined @Quentin, the browser is able to display dialog boxes, so - it has access to their HTML code. Thus, conceivably, there should be a way to see that code.

Comment: Since they aren't pages, they don't have HTML code.